# How do I programmatically trigger a mx:Button click event?

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript-3

Consider the following `mx:Button`:

```
<mx:Button click="doSomething()" id="myButton"/>
```

Is there some way to programmatically emulate the user clicking the button?

One obvious way to do it would simply be to call `doSomething()` which would give the same end result as clicking the button. But I'm specifically looking for ways to emulate the click -- that is something along the lines of `myButton.click()` (if that should have existed).

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The Button class dispatches events just like any other piece of ActionScript code: it uses the dispatchEvent method of the IEventDispatcher interface. You could invoke this yourself using this code:

`myButton.dispatchEvent(new MouseEvent(MouseEvent.CLICK));`